# ReactJS and Next.js 404 after page reload

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have a react frontend on my Wordpress blog and it works great if I run `node server.js`. I can reload on any page and it will work as expected.

On my production server if I run `node server.js` then it works fine. If I build and run `npm run start` which is set to run `next start -p 80` the website does not work properly.

Here's my `server.js` code:

```
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev: dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app

  .prepare()
  .then(() => {

    const server = express();

    server.use(compression());
    server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static', { maxAge: 31557600 }));

    server.get('/about', (req, res) => {
      app.render(req, res, '/about');
    });

    server.get('/post/:slug', (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, apiRoute: 'post' };
      app.render(req, res, '/post', queryParams);
    });

    server.get('/page/:slug', (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, apiRoute: 'page' };
      app.render(req, res, '/post', queryParams);
    });

    server.get('/city/:slug', (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, taxonomy: 'city' };
      app.render(req, res, '/category', queryParams);
    });

    server.get('/country/:slug', (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = { slug: req.params.slug, taxonomy: 'country' };
      app.render(req, res, '/category', queryParams);
    });

    server.get('/_preview/:id/:wpnonce', (req, res) => {
      const queryParams = { id: req.params.id, wpnonce: req.params.wpnonce };
      app.render(req, res, '/preview', queryParams);
    });

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(process.env.NODE_PORT, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on port " + process.env.NODE_PORT);
    });

  })

  .catch(ex => {

    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);

  });
```

When the server is running with next I can view pages and when I reload it works fine. If I try to load a blog post or category/city/country then it will always 404.

Is it an issue with the `server.js` code or a problem in the React pages for /post and /category?

Comment: You might have apache or nginx or similar that's running on port 80. Check app log messages, if it prints something on console.

Comment: It's showing the react 404 page when it's running and if I stop the react server then nothing shows.

Comment: is it availably publicly to test

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `npm run build` and then `npm run start`. You need to build the bundle first, otherwise your pages and the nextjs code are not created.

It works on dev because you don't need to build a bundle for dev, the code is accessed directly, but this is not efficient for production.

Here's the usual code for `build` and `start`:

```
"build": "next build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
```

They need to be placed in your `package.json`. You prob already have them, since you're saying you're running `npm run start`.

For more information the NextJS tutorial walks you through this in #9 of the basic - [Deploying a Next.js App](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app)